# review-board extension for tortoisehg

Tags: tortoisehg, review-board

i'm using reviewboard extension for tortoisehg and installed reviewboard on some server. Everything is good but i have one problem: i can't update existing reviews with extension because they are not loaded in the list and i can't choose any "Review ID". I can update reviews with command line (hg postreview -p -e numberOfReview) but what's the problem with extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gday,

There is a bug in the mercurial-reviewboard extension that is preventing existing reviews from being listed.

The following line of code on line 484 needs to be moved out of the "if block".

```
httpclient.set_credentials(username, password)
```

This will make sure that the http clients username is set in order to be used by pending_user_requests.

More information can be found here - http://bit.ly/f5dJTP

Cheers,
Mikey